# Template container iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am working on a homework problem and I cannot get this problem to compile:

I need to write function that accepts two iterators (for any container) and return the min and max value as a pair

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
Error   1   error C2783: 'std::pair<T,T> problem1(It,It)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'  
Error   2   error C2783: 'std::pair<T,T> problem1(It,It)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
Error   3   error C2783: 'std::pair<T,T> problem1(It,It)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

Here is my code:

```
template <typename It, typename T>
std::pair<T,T> problem1(It start, It end)
{
    // initial min max
    T min = *start;
    T max = *start;


    It curr = start;
    while (curr != end)
    {
        // check if we have a new min or max
        if (min > *curr)
            min = *curr;
        if (max < *curr)
            max = *curr;

        curr++; // get next
    }

    return std::make_pair(min, max);
}
```

The code is being tested with the following code, which I cannot modify.

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 3, 12, -8, 22, 5, 41, 33 };
std::list<double> b = { 0.8, -123, 44, 56, 12, 231 };
std::array<unsigned int, 1> c;
c[0] = 12;
auto a_ans = problem1(a.begin(), a.end());
auto b_ans = problem1(b.begin(), b.end());
auto c_ans = problem1(c.begin(), c.end());
if (*a_ans.first == -8 && *a_ans.second == 41 &&
    *b_ans.first == -123 && *b_ans.second == 231 &&
    *c_ans.first == 12 && *c_ans.second == 12) {
    std::cout << "Test 1 passed.\n";
    score += 10;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Test 1 failed.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the compiler is telling you is that it can't figure out `T` from the arguments that you provided to the function. Template parameters on a function either have to be explicitly provided (`a_ans = problem1<vector<int>::iterator, int>(a.begin(), b.begin())`), or have to be deductible from the function parameters (the compiler guesses `It` based on the `start` and `end` parameters).

Luckily, iterators have a `value_type` member:

```
template <typename It>
std::pair<typename It::value_type, typename It::value_type> problem1(It start, It end)
{
    // initial min max
    typename It::value_type min = *start;
    typename It::value_type max = *start;


    It curr = start;
    while (curr != end)
    {
        // check if we have a new min or max
        if (min > *curr)
            min = *curr;
        if (max < *curr)
            max = *curr;

        curr++; // get next
    }

    return std::make_pair(min, max);
}
```

Basically, you replace `T` with `typename It::value_type`. This works because [iterator types know their value types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/), and this works pre-C++11 too (in case your teacher is shy about new language versions).

Comment: ...and looking at the testing code, it looks like the function is expected to return a pair of iterators :/

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has no way to know what type `T` is. 
You can remove it from the template and use `decltype(*start)` instead.

The advantage of using decltype is that it will work with raw pointers and non standard iterators (unlike ::value_type)

Comment: 1) You need to decay it, and 2) it doesn't work for iterators returning proxies.